# Enable LM hash on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: passwords

I want to enable the LM hash in Windows Server 2008. How do I do that?
Can I only change it in the registry?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable them via Group Policy (secpol.msc).

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the button to change it, do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! While this may answer the question, it is recommended to give step-by-step for where to find this. Not all users are familiar with computers, and we do get lots of search engine traffic as well